# MediaPlayer : How to update progress every second?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm programming a videoplayer program and i'm searching to see the way the progress bar and time got updated every second **while mediaplayer is playing**.

I have been looking at VideoView and MediaPlayer class , but i have no found if it use a hypothetically "OnEverySecondUpdate" Listener or whatever nice (or ugly) process to do it the good way.

Any idea?

P.D : I don't use a VideoView component , i'm using a SurfaceView .

Comment: Did you try to use handler method: postDelayed? In runnable just put postDelayed again with second interval. I was using this in VideoPlayer progress update.

Comment: It sounds good ( i hadn't thought in that ) , Do you know if that is the way that MediaPlayerController use for doing it?.

Comment: anyway it runs perfect . Make it a good answer and i'll give you the tick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Handler method: postDelayed. In runnable just put postDelayed again with second interval.

Answer (score -1):

I found two relevant methods in MediaPlayer:

```
/**
     * Gets the current playback position.
     *
     * @return the current position in milliseconds
     */
    public native int getCurrentPosition();

    /**
     * Gets the duration of the file.
     *
     * @return the duration in milliseconds
     */
    public native int getDuration();
```

This is enough for u.